# Dropzone.js Rename file before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm trying to rename the files name on dropzone but the plugin stop working every time I add anything to the filename.

```
var temp = '/file-upload';
    var temp1 = '/file-delete';

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#gary-dropzone", {
        url: temp,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.tif,.pdf",
        accept: function(file, done) {
            var selected_filenames = $.map(myDropzone.files, function(selected_file) {
                return (selected_file.name.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, ''));
            });
            // var filename = file.name.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '')
            var filename = file.name.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '') 
            actuallyDelete = "YES"
            if ($.inArray(filename, selected_filenames) != selected_filenames.length - 1) {
                var error_msg = "Error! The File is already in Queue";
                done(error_msg);
                actuallyDelete = "NO"
                myDropzone.removeFile(file);
            } else {
                done();
            }
        },
        removedfile: function(file) {
            var name = file.name;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: temp1,
                data: {
                    id: name,
                    remove: actuallyDelete,
                },
                dataType: 'html'
            });
            var _ref;
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
        }
    });
```

my initial idea was to pass attribute other than name, but I can't figure out how to do so. any help on how to pass additional attributes or name change will be strongly appreciated

Comment: "my initial idea was to pass attribute other than name" - do you mean, pass to the server?

Comment: @dwright yes, any idea?

Comment: possibly adding something like `myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData){
            formData.append('newParam', 'value');
        });`